# iPhone SDK: checking which button is clicked and loading specific variables

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.1

I have 48 items each named item1,item2,item3,...,item48,etc in interface builder and have 2 strings and 1 image URL linked to each item.

ON clicked, the item present a modal view which should contains the 3 specific variables in a tableview.

how do i program such that when each item is clicked, the modal view will display the specific variables of the individual item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. You can create one view controller with tableView and use it as modalView controller. The table's data source will be an array. So you can only change content of your array on button clicks and call your modal viewController.